# Is there a way to have a variable in a string that is filled later in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, string, typescript

I want to write strings that contain variables that I can change programatically. The goal of this is to write 'rules' for a game, in which I can edit player names. For example:

*Take item from (player X) and give it to (player Y)*

In which I want to dynamically change player X and Y. I have a service in which I get a rule object, the player whose turn it is, and an eventual extra player that's needed in some rules.

in pseudocode:

```
    let ruleNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //simulate dice throw to get one of six rules
    let playerX = getCurrentPlayer();
    let playerY = getNextPlayer();
    let rule = getCurrentRule(ruleNo);  //for example, take item from playerX and give to 
                                        //playerY
    //fill player variables
```

I tried template litterals, but as I understand it I can only set these in the definition. My ideal scenario would be to create a rule object like this:

```
export object Rule {

ruleName: string;
currentPlayer: string; //to be set every time the rule is needed
ruleText: string; 
}

//in service:
let rule = {ruleName: 'foo', currentPlayer: '', ruleText: `give item to $(currentPlayer)`
```

Where I set the ruleText at game startup time in a service, and fill the player variables dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by fill player varibles dynamically. Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case for a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to me with the different rules being your strategies. If every rule depends on the current and next player, you could model that in the rule's interface:

```js
interface Rule {
    name: string;
    execute(currentPlayer: Player, nextPlayer: Player): void;
}
```

Then you could have different rule implementations like this:

```js
const rules: Rule[] = [
    {
        name: "give-item",
        execute: (currentPlayer, nextPlayer) => {
            console.log(currentPlayer.name + " gives item to " + nextPlayer.name);
        },
    },
    {
        name: "cast-spell",
        execute: (currentPlayer, nextPlayer) => {
            console.log(currentPlayer.name + " casts a spell on " + nextPlayer.name);
        },
    },
    // ...
];
```

and just pick a rule like in your code example:

```js
const currentPlayer = getCurrentPlayer();
const nextPlayer = getNextPlayer();
const ruleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
const rule = rules[ruleIndex];
rule.execute(currentPlayer, nextPlayer);
```

The key here is giving the rule objects some behavior instead of having them only store some data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your setup is or where you're storing but, but I'll assume it's either in memory or in some db/local storage.

Your approach to making it a consistent object is your best bet. Reading/parsing strings would become unmanageable at some point as you're eventually going to run into an edge case and start needing to add special characters to `split` on or something.

For starters, I'd make a model that is specific to the rule structure (without the *specifics* of the rule with it's execution data (ie: player)

```
interface IRule {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    action: string;
}
```

When I needed to add a new rule, I'd create the new object

```
const rule = {id: 1, name: 'Give Item', action: 'give-item' } as IRule;
```

Then I would make a function that was smart enough to execute the rule with the execution data

```
const executeRule = (rule: IRule, ...args: any[]) => {
    // ...
}

// Execute this rule for user 1
executeRule(rule, 1);
```

There's obviously a need to enhance your rule model so it has some sort of "manifest mapping" of what args to look for. Multiple ways to approach that.